# Store struct with deleted copy and move constructor in container

Tags: c++

I have a struct with deleted copy and move constructors and operators, but I want to add this struct to a container. How can I solve this problem?

```
class NonCopyable {
public:
    NonCopyable() = default;
    NonCopyable(NonCopyable &&) = default;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator=(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator=(NonCopyable&&) = default;
};

class NonMovable {
public:
    NonMovable() = default;
    NonMovable(NonMovable &&) = delete;
    NonMovable(const NonMovable&) = default;
    NonMovable& operator=(const NonMovable&) = default;
    NonMovable& operator=(NonMovable&&) = delete;
};

struct Data : NonCopyable, NonMovable
{
    Data(std::string str, int data)
        : m_str(std::move(str)), m_data(data) {}
private:
    std::string m_str;
    int m_data; 
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Data> table;
    table.emplace("test", Data{"data",10});
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1881:31: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, Data>'
    ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
```

Comment: You can hold the object in a unique_ptr, and store the unique_ptr in the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table.emplace("test", Data{"data",10})` will still call the move constructor of `Data`, you need to use [`std::piecewise_construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct)
to construct the `pair`:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Data> table;
table.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, 
              std::make_tuple("test"), 
              std::make_tuple("data",10));
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/ssrhbn6vP)

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair):

> ```
>  template<class... Args1, class... Args2>
>  constexpr pair(std::piecewise_construct_t,
>                 std::tuple<Args1...> first_args,
>                 std::tuple<Args2...> second_args);
> ```
>
> Forwards the elements of `first_args` to the constructor of `first` and
> forwards the elements of `second_args` to the constructor of `second`.
> This is the only non-default constructor that can be used to create a
> pair of non-copyable non-movable types.

Answer (score 3):

A more terse alternative to `piecewise_construct`:

```
table.try_emplace("test", "data", 10);
```

Comment: @康桓瑋 Neither will `emplace`. But `emplace` will unnecessarily construct a `Data` instance in that case.